# Change Visibility of Element in Template through Style

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my WPF Application I have a Custom Control with a specific Style and Template. This Control needs a new Style now which is completely the same as the first one, but changes the `Visibility` of a single Control in the Template. I don't want to copy the Styles or Templates and have duplicate code.

I know the Name of the Element and I'm trying to achieve this by doing following:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle2" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyStyle1}"
       TargetType="{x:Type MyControl}">

    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MyControlsTemplate}"/>

    <Style.Triggers>

        <!--This is just for the trigger to be triggred directly -->
        <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"> 

            <Setter TargetName="ControlToHideName" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>

        </Trigger>

    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

But it will not compile. It says that the Name "ControlToHideName" isn't recognized.

Can my idea be achieved somehow differently?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `TargetName` within a Style Setter. What you can do however is move the trigger to your `ControlTemplate` (where you *can* use the `TargetName`) and use some other property to hide that extra control.

**Example:**

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyControlsTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type MyControl}">

    <Control Name="controlToHide"/>

    <ToggleButton Name="toggleButton" IsChecked="true"/>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        <Trigger SourceName="toggleButton" Property="IsChecked" Value="True">

            <Setter TargetName="controlToHide" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />

        </Trigger>    

    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

</ControlTemplate>
```

Alternatively, you could create a new `ControlTemplate` altogether with that extra control hidden and then change the `Template` within your Style Setter.

It may be useful to know why you need this functionality, I'm sure we can come to a solution some other way.

**Edit:**

Another solution would be to create a `DependencyProperty` within your Custom Control and use that to set the visibility of your `ControlToHide`. Then, within your `Style2`, you just need to change the value of the `DependencyProperty`.

[MSDN: Implementing Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-implement-a-dependency-property)

**Control Template Example:**

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyControlsTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type MyControl}">

    <Control Name="controlToHide"/>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DependencyPropertyHideControl, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MyControl}}}" Value="True">

            <Setter TargetName="controlToHide" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />

        </DataTrigger>    

    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

</ControlTemplate>
```

**Style Example:**

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle2" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyStyle1}"
   TargetType="{x:Type MyControl}">

    <Setter Property="DependencyPropertyHideControl" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MyControlsTemplate}"/>

</Style>
```

Comment: The Problem is that the Template has over 300 lines of XAML. I dont want to have this twice.

When my CustomControl is inside another Control. Lets say in a StackPanel" i dont want that "ControlToHideName" to be visible. What i dont want too, is a change in the original Code.

Comment: On what condition does this extra control in your template need to be hidden? What significance does it have?

Comment: When the "MyStyle2" is set :)

Comment: Check out my Edits.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct, because i think the Idea with the DependencyProperty is the only clean way to achieve this. I thought about that too, but wanted to see if there are any other solutions to my problem :)